# prove $\neg p\implies (p\implies q)$ without using the deduction theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

prove $\neg p\implies (p\implies q)$ without using the deduction theorem

Axioms to be used are:

a)$A\implies(B\implies A)$

b)$(A\implies(B\implies C)\implies((A\implies B)\implies(A\implies C))$

c)$(\neg A\implies\neg B)\implies(B\implies A)$

Althogh by using the deduction thoerem the proof is very short and easy,using only the above axioms  it seams impossible
Can enybody give me at least a starting point

deduction theorem proof:

1)$\neg p$..................assumption

2)$\neg p\implies(\neg q\implies\neg p)$.............................by (a)

3)($\neg q\implies\neg p)$..........................................by 1,2 m.p

4)($\neg q\implies\neg p)\implies (p\implies q)$......................by (c)

5)$p\implies q$.......................................................by 3,4 m.p

Comment: I am guessing that you are not allowed to use a *truth-table* instead.  Is this correct?

Comment: yes you are right we want a syntactical proof and not a semantical one (truth tables).beside the truth tables they do not provide a proof ,but can only decide whether there is a proof or not

Comment: "beside the truth tables they do not provide a proof" : depends on your definition of proof.  I define proof to signify that you have demonstrated that it is impossible for an assertion to be false/inaccurate.  From that perspective, truth tables do provide proof.

Comment: Since you have a proof using the deduction theorem, the only thing you have to do is follow the proof of the deduction theorem itself for your concrete formulas.

Comment: please be so kind to show me ,because this is what i have been trying to do for so long

Answer (score 2):

To derive $\neg p\to(p\to q)$, you will want substituting $A:=\neg p$ and $C:=p\to q$ into schema (b) to build the following for some useful $B$ .

$\qquad(\neg p\to(B\to (p\to q)))\to((\neg p\to B)\to(\neg p\to (p\to q)))$

Schema (a) lets us build $\neg p\to (\neg q\to\neg p)$, so if $B$ were $\neg q\to\neg p$ the above would be

$\qquad(\neg p\to((\neg q\to\neg p)\to (p\to q)))\to((\neg p\to (\neg q\to\neg p))\to(\neg p\to (p\to q)))$

With $\neg p\to(\neg q\to \neg p)$ available from schema (a), and $(\neg q\to\neg p)\to (p\to q)$ from schema (c) we would then just need to derive $\neg p\to((\neg q\to\neg p)\to(p\to q))$ and ...

That starts you off

---

a) $A\to(B\to A)$

b) $(A\to(B\to C))\to((A\to B)\to(A\to C))$

c) $(\neg A\to\neg B)\to(B\to A)$

1. $(\neg p\to((\neg q\to\neg p)\to (p\to q)))\to((\neg p\to (\neg q\to\neg p))\to(\neg p\to (p\to q)))~$ from (b)
2. $~~\neg p\to(\neg q\to\neg p)~$ from (a)
3. $~~(\neg q\to \neg p)\to (p\to q)~$ from (c)
4. $\text{something}$
5. $\neg p\to((\neg q\to \neg p)\to (p\to q))~$ somehow
6. Continue.

Comment: how do i get line 5 in your proof,because i tried hard and i could not get that

Comment: Derive the something on line 4 from one of the schema that will allow you to use *modus ponens* with line 3. @user149368

Comment: which schema do you seggest i try

Comment: The one which works.  @user149368 $$\begin{split} &(\neg q\to\neg p)\to(p\to q)\\&\text{some conditional statement}\\\hline&\neg p\to((\neg q\to\neg p)\to(p\to q)) \end{split}{\lower{1ex}{\text{modus ponens}}}$$

Comment: yes you right  i got it  thanks ,but in which way that complies with the deduction theorem? i mean in which way the deduction theorem show us the way to aproof without using the deduction theorem

Comment: You are building a proof *without using the deduction theorem*.